# Interval when using TimerTask in conjunction with Timer is not working

Tags: java, android, timer, intervals

I am using `timer.schedule(minuteTask, 0, 1000*60)`  to generate a new color at regular intervals. As you can see by the gif below that I recorded, the interval does not seem to be working.

[image: Annoying blinking gif]

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask minuteTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
        int r = random.nextInt(255);
        int g = random.nextInt(255);
        int b = random.nextInt(255);
    }
};

timer.schedule(minuteTask, 0, 1000*60);
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Seems as if you don't account for the EDT. Try using a swing `Timer`

Comment: don't use Timers, use Handlers instead

Comment: @pskink Thanks for the tip. After doing some research I found out that handler are better. It works now :) I'm using handler.postDelayed();

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(
    new TimerTask() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            //put UR code herr
        } 
    }, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you should use the `scheduleAtFixedRate(..)` function of Timer. This will help you to change the color in given time interval.

A simple schedule() method will execute at once while `scheduleAtFixedRate()` method takes and extra parameter which is for repetition of the task again & again on specific time interval.

Look at below code snippet:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
timer.schedule( new performClass(), 30000 );
```

This is going to perform once after the 30 Second Time Period Interval is over. A kind of timeoput-action.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); 
//timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, delay, period);
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new performClass(), 1000, 30000 );
```

This is going to start after 1 second and will repeat on every 30 seconds time interval.